# How to insert a date string in a paragraph in Quarto

Tags: quarto

I'm new to Quarto for document generation and want to insert a date string.  I understand that one can add it to the YAML header at the beginning of the file, but this puts the date in a pre-designated spot.  I want to insert a date (i.e. "10/11/22") within a paragraph later in the text.  Is there a way to insert "fields" or variables within text?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`meta` shortcode](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/variables.html#meta). The `meta` shortcode allows you to insert content from Pandoc metadata (e.g. YAML fields at the top of the document)

So to use the date field from YAML metadata, use `{{< meta date >}}` in the paragraph or anywhere you want to use the date meta data.

```
---
title: "Document metadata"
format: html
date: "10/11/22"
date-format: "DD/MM/YY"
---

## Quarto

This document was published at {{< meta date >}}
```

And Quarto supports a varying way of date formatting, see [Quarto Dates and Date Formatting](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/dates.html) from the docs.

---

[image: adding meta data in the document]

---